# Find the volume between intersection of two surfaces?

Tags: volume

How to find the volume between the two intersecting surfaces?

$z^2 = x^2 + 3y^2$

$z = 8 - x^2 - y^2$

Please shown the steps needed to solve the problem.

Or show me the direction to go to solve this problem.

Things I tried, that I thought brought me closer to solution.

$x = r \sin(\theta),  y = r\cos(\theta)$

we get

$z^2 = r^2 + 2 r^2 \cos^2(\theta) $

and

$z = 8 - r^2 $

equating them I got

$z = {\dfrac{8}{(1 - \sqrt{2 \cos(2 \theta)})}}^{\tfrac{1}{2}}$

I have no idea how to proceed from here, as I cannot find the integration limits.

After curve were plottes, they were smooth, projections appear have a linear profile
[image: Profile]
[image: Projection]

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: Polar coordinates might help

Comment: Tried to find the intersction curve, changed to question to polar coordinates, plotted the curve . .

Comment: Can you show us your steps? Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @TobyMak I have added the thing I have tried last.

Comment: Don't you mean between two *surfaces* ?

Comment: Ya.. My mistake.

Comment: @Raptor Is the first solid $z = x^2 + 3y^2$ or $z^2 = z^2 + 3y^2$? Can you check? Next, does the question tell you to find volume for $z \geq 0$? If not, please note $z^2 = x^2 + 3y^2$ represents two elliptic cones one above $z-$plane and one below and both intersect the given paraboloid. Technically there is also volume bound between two cones and paraboloid.

Comment: This was asked as such in a multilple choice questionaire. I dont have its answer. I have the info about both the nature of surfaces and need to find the  included area.